# Multiple Monitors with one DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I've read that DisplayPort supports multiple monitors. My question is how can I connect 3 monitors with one display port, is there such a splitter? I have 2 DVI monitors and one VGA (which I could use DVI to VGA convereter)

If I could do it, will I be limitted by the GPU? Is it possible that my GPU only allow for 2 monitors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DisplayPort Spec supports the daisy chaining of multiple monitors, but not the splitting of the signal.  Unfortunate, to support this you need to have at least 2 DisplayPort equipped monitors that support daisy chaining (of which there are none to my knowledge).

Given your situation, your best bet would be something like the [Matrox TripleHead ToGo](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/?productTabs=1#close), which allows you to connect multiple monitors to a single port (and tricks your computer into only seeing one while spreading the image across several).

Using a solution like that, your main limitation is the power of your graphics card and how many pixels it can render well.

Comment: He is correct. Both ends of the connection also have to support DisplayPort 1.2. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)

Comment: Actually, according to their [FAQ](http://www.displayport.org/faq/):
A PC with one DP connector is driving two monitors via daisy chaining. The 1st monitor is a DP v1.2 monitor with input and output connectors. The 2nd monitor is a DP v1.1a monitor. DP v1.2 PC—> DP v1.2 monitor with in & out connectors—->DP v.1.1a monitor.

Comment: @MattVobori what happens if you use a legacy non-DP (VGA/DVI) monitor as the 2nd monitor by connecting the 1st monitor to it via  `DP monitor 1`<---> `DP-in to VGA/DVI adapter`<--> `non-DP monitor 2`? I'm guessing it won't work but thought I would ask anyway..

Comment: From my usage, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

DisplayPort 1.2 supports daisy-chaining like this in the spec, but I am not aware of any products on the market that currently support it, either on the video card side or the monitor side.  I expect you'll see them in the next year or so, though, now that the specifications are official (and I believe there are already controllers entering production).

Comment: Also note that DisplayPort -> VGA isn't possible without an expensive active converter.  While DVI can carry digital and analog signals, and so can convert either way passively, DisplayPort is digital-only.

Comment: Pretty sure its 1.2 that supports daisy-chaining. They didn't bump the bandwidth in 1.1.  http://www.reghardware.com/2009/01/13/displayport_1dot2_basics/  and $16 isn't what I would consider an "expensive" converter: http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024609&p_id=6019&seq=1&format=2

Comment: @peelman - It is 1.2.  I edited that before you posted, it was a typo.  SE really should flash a notice when something you're responding to changes. :/

Comment: @peelman - Also, Monoprice is fairly unique in their low prices for this sort of thing (even they list it at a $50 "normal price") and so for persons who either don't want to or can't do business with them (mostly persons outside the US, I would suspect) I would indeed call something from anybody else expensive.

Comment: Yeah, i see that now :-\  apologies for the too-fast correction.