# Displayport 1.2 Daisychain Hub - which keywords to search?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining

While attempting to look for a device that allows me to drive multiple monitors from my single Displayport (1.2), I noticed that most search results were splitters that merely duplicate the input signal to produce 2 identical output signals, instead of allowing independent signals. Often these aren't even clearly marked as such. Essentially I want a device that allows me to connect 2 monitors that don't support daisychaining, as if they would support daisychaining.

I find it hard to search for what I want because I don't know the correct terminology. My question is, which are the correct keywords that describe the device I'm looking for?

Comment: ["Daisy-chain"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_chain_(electrical_engineering)) and "hub" are actually competing ideas.  A daisy-chain is one device chained from the last with no central "hub".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a real DisplayPort hub/splitter](http://superuser.com/questions/230744/looking-for-a-real-displayport-hub-splitter), http://superuser.com/questions/282232/multiple-monitors-with-one-displayport?rq=1

Comment: @techie007 This question is about the correct technical terms to refer to these devices. That question (from 2011) is about specific devices/buying choices, which is actually not a supported type of question on superuser. That question also doesn't seem to use the correct term (I now think it's probably "Multi-Stream Transport Hub"), so it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: while I see what you're driving at, I'm not sure "What is this thing called" is a valid question for SU either.  But hey, takes more than just my vote to close things. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems "Multi-Stream Transport" or "MST" are the magic words. I finally got good search results by looking for "Displayport 1.2 MST hub".

Comment: Or "multi-display adapter" also gives decent results